# Square room, walls to bend to create round celling angles

Tags: modeling

I created walls from 2D plans. In reality, the ceiling angles are rounded. The roundings are quite marked. The ceiling corresponds to a luminous square (in yellow).
1. can the red and blue vertices be glued together again to recreate the rounding?
2. Is there a simpler method? Connect to the ceiling square for example? on delete te top of the walls to recreate the round-angle celling ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending a bit on your other requirements, perhaps the simplest way would be to reduce the corners to a cube. and *then* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel the vertices at the corners.

[image]

If you want to leave yourself some flexibility, you could do this with a Bevel Modifier, set to 'Only Vertices' and 'Weight' adjusting the Vertex Bevel Weight of the corners you want rounded, and the profile, segments, etc., whenever you like...

[image]